# Will diode be turned on?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, diodes, analog

Assuming we have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9jbpK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming D1 is a silicon diode and D3 is a germanium diode,Will D1 be turned on so the VAB  = Vfd1 or not?

I know that if we didnt have the resistor D1 would not turn on but now i am unsure.I also know that if we had a resistor ,with a smaller resistance than R1, in series with D1 both would turn on.

[[image]]

I assumed that D1 conducts and found the current 0.003A.But I assumed D1 conducts it may not what should I do from here?

Comment: As a follow-up to your prior question: Both will be turned on to different levels of current, if we use the accurate exponential model. If you want to use the constant-voltage-drop model, please try applying the analytical techniques I presented in my answer, and share what you find.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do *you* think? What will VAB be if D1 is not there? Is that greater than D1's Vf?

Comment: I know that if we didnt have the resistor D1 would not turn on but now i am unsure.I also know that if we had a resistor in series with D1 and it had less resitance than R1 both would turn on.

Comment: This is almost exactly a rehash of the answer I gave, except with one of the resistors set equal to zero ohms. Try solving it in that way and then see whether you get a sensible solution you understand (and if not, post what you get here so we can discuss it)

Comment: One way to solve this is learn and use a circuit simulator like LTspice and check it. It is simple, fast and efficient.

Comment: @nanofarad yes it started bugging me  an hour ago and I cant stop thinking it.

Comment: @MissMulan Then go ahead, apply that solution technique, and show what you find *including your interpretation of the results and any points of confusion that remain thereafter* -- that will be a far better starting point for clearing up your confusion than the info we have right now.

Comment: We don't hand out solutions to homework or quiz questions here. Since this is not a practical circuit we assume that it is of academic interest only and we expect you to demonstrate a significant effort to solve this yourself. Show us **all** of your work.

Comment: This is so close to your previous question, and as @nanofarad says, you've not addressed anything you've learned from his (or any other answer):

Comment: Wait I will post where I am getting confused.

Comment: Please add your equations as text in the question. Your snapshot is very difficult to read.

Comment: I dont know MathJax.

Comment: It's not hard to learn, and you will find that similar syntax is used in lots of places. You would be showing appreciation for those who take the time to try to help you if in turn you would try to help them.

Comment: Ok i will try to learn

Comment: For solving question of if VAB = Vfd1, you can assume the forward voltage drop for both diodes and use that to calculate nodal voltages and currents. 
However, that's an approximation, so to get more accurate approximation find the resulting forward voltage given the diode current calculated (dependence found in datasheet for real diode) and then recalculate nodal currents and voltages (a better approximation). This can be iterated for more accuracy, but in practice simulation makes it easier..
One caveat is that assumption can be wrong in some cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assumed that D1 conducts and found the current 0.003A.But I assumed D1 conducts it may not what should I do from here?

If

- you are using an "on/off" model of diode conduction (as opposed to an exponential current/voltage relationship)
- and you have calculated all the voltages and currents in the circuit assuming all the diodes conduct,
- and for every node in your circuit, the sum of all currents entering that node is equal to the sum of all the currents leaving that node,
- the (conventional) current through each diode flows from positive to negative

then

- you are done.

For example if you have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUoo98.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and you assume that there is 0.7V across D1, and you calculate that the currents through the components are

- \$I_{R1} = 20\$ mA
- \$I_{R2} = 7\$ mA
- \$I_{R3} = 13\$ mA (which is positive)

and the voltages across components are

- \$V_{R1} = 2\$ V
- \$V_{R2} = 0.7\$ V
- \$V_{D1} = 0.7\$ V

And the sum of voltages around any loop is 0, and the algebraic sum of currents into any node is 0 and the (conventional) current through the diode D1 is from positive to negative. So you are done.

However, suppose you are analyzing the following circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUazCP.png)</sup>

And you calculate as follows:

- D1 has a drop of 0.7V
- R2 is in parallel with D1, so it also has a drop of 0.7V
- R1 has a voltage drop of V1 - \$V_{D1}\$ = 2.7 - 0.7 = 2V
- R1 has a current of \$\frac{2V}{440\Omega} = \$ 4.545 mA
- R2 has a current of \$\frac{0.7V}{100\Omega} = \$ 7 mA
- D1 has a current of \$I_{R1} - I_{R2} = 4.545-7 = -2.455\$ mA

Then you would see that the (conventional) current in D1 is flowing from the negative to the positive. So, the assumption that D1 conducting is invalid, and you need to recalculate the voltages and currents in the circuit using the assumption that D1 is not conducting.

Now, it is possible that you calculated the voltages and currents in the circuit in a different way that presented here. Calculating in a different way may result in different values. However, in the end, the signal that the diode is not conducting is one of the following.

- the algebraic sum of voltages around a loop is not 0
- the algebraic sum of currents into a node is not 0
- the (conventional) current through the diode is from negative to positive

Any of these conditions signify that the assumption about the diode is incorrect.